# Can I install ChromiumOS on old Raspberry Pi B+?

Tags: kodi, chromium, pi-b+, media, chrome-os

**Dumb question: Please dont redirect me to other stack exchanges**

I know its possible to install ChromiumOS (not chromium) on Raspberry Pi 2 and 3, but I wanna know **if its possible on RPi B+(the first model rPi**).  If it is possible, which build should I install (link to the said version would be very much appreciated).

Also, even if I get around to installing it, can I watch YouTube and play videos using it? I dont want any of the other features, just YouTube and other video streaming apps.

The reason I dont wanna use Kodi is because it is too buggy and most extensions are illegal to use. Also, I hate the Youtube addon. I'd rather use Youtube on TV.

If chromiumOS is not possible, is there any other thing that I can effectively use to stream video (maybe like chromecast)?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @MatsK enough. ChromiumOS is supported on RPi 2 and 3. But some guy said theoretically it is possible to install chromiumOS on all ARM based devices. And I downloaded one of the images and I wrote it to a SD Card and stuck it into my Pi. Both lights light up and... nothing happens, the lights are not blinking, just lit up. I figured this wont work. Hence, asked the question.
Used XBMC (official build and no-limits build). Not impressed.
Also some people told me that the first model RPi is too bad for streaming video. 

yeah. thats all i did.